# How to find the element that displays and hides with in 2 seconds in selenium webdriver using python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to wait for a page to load and take screenshots using python selenium but the element disappears after 2 seconds.
I used `WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'msgBox success')))` but not worked.

```
<span id="attachCVMsgBox" tabindex="-1"><div><div tabindex="0" class="msgBox success"><div class="cnt"><i class="icon">Success</i><p class="head">Success</p><p class="msg">Resume has been successfully uploaded.</p></div></div></div></span>
```

[image]

I want to take a screenshot when I get success

Comment: OK, what have you tried to achieve that? What problems have you faced?

Comment: Sounds like you might actually be talking about an alert message? If so you might need to use  .until(ec.alert_is_present()

Comment: After uploading file it get success message and then disappear

Comment: better show URL for this page so we could see real, full version.

Comment: Naukri website after resume updated it get a success message and after that, it disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get the element by following the code by using Xpath

```
WebDriverWait(browser,100).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="attachCVMsgBox"]/div')))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).